# Grails 1.3.5 and Spring Security Core

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have build a grails application, which on login redirects users to different URLs based on User's role (custom roles defined in roles domain). Now I am trying to integrate Spring Security Core Grails Plugin to the application, so plan to use the plugin's domain model.

I understand the auth action in LoginController does the user login validation and if the user is logged in the redirects to default target URI.
My question is how can I know if the logging in user is of type ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER or any other ROLE? How can I check the authority here and then redirect to different URIs?

I would also like to know how the user validation is done i.e. how & where the username and password are validated against the database in spring security?

Thank You.
Jay Chandran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The redirect happens in `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` but the plugin extends this class in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to support Ajax logins.

If you want to customize the redirect location based on roles, I'd subclass `AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and override `onAuthenticationSuccess()`. You'll have access to the Authentication, so you can inspect the granted authorities and determine where to go based on those.

Then replace the plugin's bean with yours in resources.groovy:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

beans = {
   authenticationSuccessHandler(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
      def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

      requestCache = ref('requestCache')
      redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
      defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
      alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault
      targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter
      ajaxSuccessUrl = conf.successHandler.ajaxSuccessUrl
      useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sure I will have more queries.