# Injecting LdapTemplate to return user details inside a Grails service causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I've been struggling with Spring Security LDAP for a while now, and just when I finally thought I had it beaten into submission, its tripped me up again.

The scenario:  I'm having users log in using their organisation credentials, which I then check against the internal user database.  If they don't exist, I create them locally and then set their local authorities (I can't touch the LDAP server, only authenticate against it - so I can't add the authorities there).  This works fine... but I then want to add a couple of fields from LDAP - their full name and email address, and this is where it goes wrong.

I have LDAP searches working in a controller - using the following code (I've injected ldapTemplate further up):

```
def fullName = ldapTemplate.search("", "(uid=" + uid + "*)", new AttributesMapper() {
        @Override
        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
            return attrs.get("cn").get()
        }
    })
```

and this works perfectly.  But when I replicate this code in a service that is called post-authentication the ldapTemplate is always null... I've tried a few different things, but I can't get it to populate properly... can anyone shed some light on why?  I'm hoping its something stupid I'm doing since its 4:21am and I should have been in bed about 6 hours ago...

EDIT:  Here is the service code as requested, thanks for taking a look Burt - its currently not very robust as I haven't got it working past simply creating a new local user - there is work to do on it yet.

```
package com.myPackage

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils

class PostAuthHandlerService implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

def springSecurityService
def ldapTemplate

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler target = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
private List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {
    def username = auth.principal.getAt("username")
    User.withTransaction { status ->
        // Check to see if this user exists in the local db
        def user = User.findByUsername(username)
        if (!user) { // User doesn't exist yet, so create and make a user...
            def userRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?:
                    new Role(authority: 'ROLE_AM').save(failOnError: true)
            user = new User(
                    username: username,
                    password: auth.getCredentials() ?: placeholderPassword(),
                    displayName: getLdapDetails("username", "cn") ?: "",
                    email: getLdapDetails("username", "mail") ?: "",
                    enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
            UserRole.create user, userRole
        }
        else {
            println("--- You exist already! Updating details")
            user.displayName = getLdapDetails("username", "cn") ?: ""
        }
        target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth)
    }
}

def getLdapDetails(username, attr) {
    return ldapTemplate.search("", "(uid=$username*)", new AttributesMapper() {
        @Override
        public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
            return attrs.get(attr).get()
        }
    })
}

def placeholderPassword () {
    // This is here because we also allow local logins for some users.  
    // If the password is not available, then create a big ugly one...
    return org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(128)
}

public void proceed(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {
    target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth)
}
```

}

2nd Edit: I've been trying various different things - including trying to use springSecurityService.reauthenticate to get the local user to be used during the session rather than the LDAP one - and this bean is null as well... it seems like I can't inject any beans into my service at all.

I eventually found this post: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993 which gave me a workaround and I now have it working... but I'd still like to know why it didn't in the first place... I have so much to learn in Grails - and its hard to know where to start.

Cheers in advance

Steve

Comment: So it has nothing to do with LDAP, and is a dependency injection question? Please post the service code.

Comment: I think you're right, since it works elsewhere... and now I think about it I did try putting the original search code (which is working fine now with all the code in the controller) into a service early on and it didn't work... I never made that connection at 4am.  Coding for 20 hours straight is obviously a bad idea, unless you're actually doing it - then it seems fine :)

Comment: Burt, your (rhetorical?) question got me on the right track... Could you possibly explain (in an answer, so I can accept it) why (or most likely why) this problem occurred? Cheers, Steve

Comment: I have the following in resources.groovy postAuthHandlerService (PostAuthHandlerService, ref('ldapTemplate')) but I am getting the following: error creating bean with name 'postAuthHandlerService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ldapTemplate' is defined
Can you share where and how you have the ldapTemplate bean populated with the ldap source?

Comment: Is there any equivalent example to this in Grails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you injecting authenticationSuccessHandler ? You should try defining authenticationSuccessHandler in resources.xml

[Grails 1.3.5 and Spring Security Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887875/grails-1-3-5-and-spring-security-core)

Comment: Cheers for the reply.  I'm using Grails 2, and have this bean in resources.groovy: authenticationSuccessHandler(com.myPackage.PostAuthHandlerService) {
 }

Comment: You should set ldapTemplate proprty of authenticationHandler.. mauthenticationSuccessHandler(com.myPackage.PostAuthHandlerService) { **ldapTemplate=ref(ldapTemplate)**}

Comment: I will try that and let you know how I get on... thanks for the tip.  If it works, I will accept the answer...

Comment: Brilliant... that worked.  Could you tell me what the difference between that and adding ", ref(ldapTemplate)" in the bean signature is?

Comment: resources.xml is similar to application-context.xml. So you will have to declare all dependency manually if you are loading a bean via resources.xml. that means authenticationSuccessHandler(com.myPackage.PostAuthHandlerService) { } will instantiate authentication handler without any ldapTemplate.

Comment: I have the following in resources.groovy postAuthHandlerService (PostAuthHandlerService, ref('ldapTemplate')) but I am getting the following: error creating bean with name 'postAuthHandlerService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ldapTemplate' is defined
Can you share where and how you have the ldapTemplate bean populated with the ldap source?

Comment: @Viriato Sorry this was a project I did at university 4 years ago.  I had so much trouble with Grails and Spring that as soon as the project ended I brain-dumped the whole lot and moved on to other frameworks - I can't remember much about it at all, other than a distinct feeling that it was deliberately trying to make me feel stupid.  Best of luck with it.