# Grails: Inject LdapTemplate from spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I'm using the spring security (core 2.0-SNAPSHOT and ldap 2.0-RC2) plugins in my Grails 2.4.RC1 project.  I'd like to be able to reuse the `LdapTemplate` that has been configured for use in spring security but I'm not sure how to inject the `LdapTemplate` into my service class.

Here's my simple service:

```
@Transactional
class EmployeeSynchronizationService implements EmployeeSynchronizer {

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate

void syncEmployees() {
  // do work with ldapTemplate... but ldapTemplate is null
  println ldapTemplate
  sync(getUsernameToEmployeeMap(), getEmployeeLdapInfo())
}
...
```

And based on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146378/225217), my resources.groovy file looks like this:

```
beans = { 
  employeeSynchronizer(employee.EmployeeSynchronizationService) {
    ldapTemplate=ref(ldapTemplate)
  }
}
```

However, when I inject the `EmployeeSynchronizer` into a controller and invoke its `syncEmployees` method I see that the LdapTemplate is null.

Note: this same question was asked (but not answered) [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-LDAP-template-td4639795.html).